# HTML upload file directory does not exist

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to upload a file using an HTML form and php, the code goes like this:

```
$targetPictureLocation = "/files/images/team/" . strtolower(str_replace(" ","", $_POST['name'])) . ".png";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPictureLocation);
```

Now I believe the *`$targetPictureLocation`* refrences `www.domain.com/targetpath/` because there is a slash infront of files.  Is this proper?  If so then the directory does exist however I am getting these errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/files/images/team/foobar.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/08/11798508/html/domainname/files/scripts/userManagement.php on line 259

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpwzO4X7' to '/files/images/team/foobar.png' in /home/content/08/11798508/html/domainname/files/scripts/userManagement.php on line 259
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/domainname/files/images/team/" . strtolower(str_replace(" ","", $_POST['name'])) . ".png";` in `$tartgetPictureLocation`

Comment: same error except there is no `domainname` in the path as shown in the original errors

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47580/html-upload-file-directory-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$targetPictureLocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/domainname/files/images/team/" . strtolower(str_replace(" ","", $_POST['name'])) . ".png";`
```

You are only adding the relative path which will point PHP to :

> /home/content/08/11798508/html/domainname/files/scripts/files/images/team/

which is the wrong location. **PHP**'s `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will return the scripts' base directory URL. Since the folder you want to upload is in the parent folder. You should use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and the location becomes :

> /home/content/08/11798508/html/domainname/files/images/team/